# Windows Store promotional codes, unexpected error

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am trying to distribute a Windows 10 app to our client via promotional codes generated in the Windows Dev Center "dashboard". But when I try to use the generated codes via http://microsoft.com/redeem, I get the following error message:

"Sorry but an unexpected error occurred. The error has been recorded and we will investigate. Please try to redeem your code later".

The app is uploaded and submitted. In the status field it says:

```
Detailed publishing status for this submission
Customers               Can get packages        Can see Store listing
Windows 10 clients              ✓                   pending
```

In "Pricing and availability" the app is set to: "Hide this app and prevent acquisition. Customers with a promotional code can still download it on Windows 10 devices."

I have no clue where to begin to resolve this issue, so any information would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I had the same issue and simply waiting for some time resolved it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I eventually wrote Microsoft support who said the same, and after waiting about 48 hours, the code worked. I certainly hope I wont have to wait that long everytime I push an update, since this currently is the way we get the app to our client for verification.

Comment: I don't know if requesting new promotional codes always takes this long, but getting updates certified doesn't. It's usually a matter of about 2 hours for an update to pass.

Comment: Shouldn't your comment be posted as an answer? You were correct.

Comment: Thanks guys, you just gave me a new hope ;)
I'm in this situation for 8 hours now...

Comment: Marco, I'm in this situation for more than 24 hours now... :(

Answer (score -1):

I just spent 30 mins on chat with Microsoft and they're pretty good. 2 things can cause this error:
- reverse compatibility. If you're trying to install an Xbox 360 game on Xbox One it won't work. You have to install it on the 360. If I've got that wrong you know what I mean
- region settings. Your regions must be set the same as where you're living.